# Correction Factor for np.fft.rfft

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, magnitude

I tested the function `np.fft.rfft` using the following code and determined the magnitude of a $50 \, \textrm{Hz}$ sine wave.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
frequency = 50
f_sam = 192000  # sampling freq
dt = 1/f_sam  # time step
t = np.arange(0, 1/frequency*2, dt)

# 5V 50Hz-sine wave
y = 5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * t)

# Compute the one-sided frequency spectrum
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(y), dt)
fft_magnitude = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y)) / len(fft_magnitude)
```

As the sine wave has an amplitude of $5 \, \textrm{V}$ I get an expected peak at $50 \, \textrm{Hz}$ with $5 \, \textrm{V}$.
However, why doesn't it require a correction factor of $2$ (e.g. `fft_magnitude = **2** * np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y)) / len(fft_magnitude)`)?
This should be done when discarding the left-hand side (negative frequencies) of the frequency spectrum, but why isn't it necessary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably because of the following line

> `fft_magnitude = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y)) / len(fft_magnitude)`

This doesn't run as is because `fft_magnitude` isn't defined at this point so you can't determine the length of it (unless you run it twice or more).

The issue here is that the FFT length (`len(y)`) is 7680 but `rfft()` returns only the positive frequencies plus DC and Nyquist for a total of 3841 points, which is NOT the FFT length. You are normalizing my the wrong lenght.

Try `fft_magnitude = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y)) / len(y)`

Comment: Yes, thanks, that solves my issue. I forgot about that.